# "there are no allowed placeholders" - why can't I add forms to my presentation?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore7.2

I'm running Sitecore 7.2 with Web Forms For Marketers 2.4.

I have a placeholder settings `main`. That placeholder has the WFFM `form` control listed under "allowed controls". The "restricting placeholders" app also lists the `main` placeholder as the only selected placeholder.

I have a layout `standard` that points at a .cshtml file `Standard.cshtml`.

I have a template `standard page`. On the `__Standard values` of that template I've defined a presentation under the "default" device: layout is `standard`, and the `main` placeholder is listed under "placeholder settings".

My understanding is that I should be able to "insert form" onto either the `__Standard values` or on to content item instances of the `standard page` template. But every time I try either of those I get "there are no allowed placeholders in order to insert a new form". What do I need to do to get WFFM to let me add a form to my items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have everything setup correctly in order to insert a form into the `main` placeholder (possible security issues, notwithstanding). I believe the issue is the fact that the WFFM module is strictly Web Forms only at the moment and does not work with MVC layouts and renderings. Because your layout is a **.cshtml** file, Sitecore will trigger the MVC pipeline.

Apparently there is an update in the works that will support MVC and possibly support for a wizard / multi-stepped feature.

In the meantime, I have had to work around the issue by creating separate ASPX layouts / templates for form landing pages like the one below. The downside here is that you have to manage separate code paths for both MVC and Web Forms.

https://www.montereybayaquarium.org/support-us/membership/become-a-member-now

Answer (score 2):

WFFM doesn't work with Sitecore MVC. Sad panda.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/522918

There are a couple of workarounds floating around (e.g. http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2014/02/11/usercontrol-renderings-in-a-sitecore-mvc-website-wffm-for-mvc/), but I don't think they're supported.